# Comparing Working and Member Revision in MKS

Tags: mks

I want to get a list of all the files whose working revision and member revision are different. There is a command to get revisioninfo of a file (si revisioninfo) but the working file version is not displayed. Is there a command to get the working file version?
Bottomline: I want to programatically check if all files in project are updated, if not show the list of files which are not updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a nice way to get a list of space separated values for name, memberrev and workingrev:

```
si viewsandbox --fields=name,memberrev,workingrev --[no]recurse
```

Add additional options to the command, like the sandbox-path and a filter to not see the pj-files.